# Setting TextLabel Position Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, positioning, textlabel

I have a Scroll View with many objects in it,since i cant edit the position on scrollview in InterfaceBuilder,how i set the position of the object programmactily?
Something like:

```
myTextField.x = 50;
myTextField.y = 540;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the frame property to set it relative to the superview's coordinates like this:

```
myTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

There is no textlabel but I assume you mean either `UITextField` or `UILabel`, either way both inherit from `UIView` and have the frame property.

Answer (score 0):

You could also move it according to the object's center.

```
float x = 220; //Change This Number
float y = 180; //Change This Number

myTextField.center = CGPointMake(x,y);
```